# Allow invalid HTML characters in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am using Saxon & XSLT to transform HTML documents, over which I have no control.

These documents may contain characters that should really be encoded, e.g.

™

instead of the encoded

```
&#153;
```

As it stands, Saxon is throwing the following exception during the transform, from [HTMLEmitter](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/net/sf/saxon/event/HTMLEmitter.java.html):

```
else if (c >= 127 && c < 160) {
                       // these control characters are illegal in HTML
                       DynamicError err = new DynamicError(
                        "Illegal HTML character: decimal " + (int) c);
                        err.setErrorCode("SERE0014");
                        throw err;
```

Is there anyway to be more lenient, and tell Saxon to ignore and let through these characters as they are - or - how do I configure Saxon to use the XMLEmitter and not the HTMLEmitter?

Comment: XML allows arbitrary characters as long as the encoding is right. The only exceptions are the usual: `<>'"&` which have to be expressed via entity references. Also, what is an _HTML character_?

Comment: @Dimitre: This is a fair `xslt` question.

Comment: @Alejandro: I would agree if the title of the question was correct and if it didn't ask just for Saxon. In the title the question is how to work with invalid XML characters with Saxon, while what the OP really wants is how to output certain special characters.

Comment: @Dimitre: Fair enough, correcting title also...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That character IS invalid in HTML because it will not necessarily render as what you expect, depending on the user's code page.  You want to use the correct code point, `&#x2122;` and make sure to use UTF-8 encoding.

EDIT: character-map

```
<xsl:character-map name="TM">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#153;" string="&#x2122;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

Comment: I know it is invalid HTML, but for the sake of argument, is there anyway to ignore it anyway. I absolutely can NOT change the source HTML.

Comment: Can you use a character-map in your XSLT to transform the invalid character to the correct encoding?

Comment: that works perfectly, assuming I add every character between 127 and 160. Will there be a significant performance hit for doing this?

Comment: I would expect the map lookup to O(1) since it's a simple array index, so the performance hit will probably be slight.

Answer (score 2):

Saxon is an XSLT processor, not an XML parser. If you get errors parsing input documents then it is the XML parser (and not Saxon) complaining and that means your input is not well-formed XML. On the Java platform if the input is HTML and not XML you might get away with using something like TagSoup http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/ instead of an XML parser.

On the other hand I agree with the comment already made, XNL builds on and supports Unicode so your input document can use Unicode characters as long as the documents are properly encoded and declare the used encoding in the XML declaration. With Unicode the code point of '™' is 8482, not 153. I suppose your input documents use a Windows code page like 1252, in that case your documents need to start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>` to let the XML parser know.

Comment: OK, but assuming I absolutely can not change the source HTML, and assuming the source encoding declaration is wrong, is there a way to pass this through (and yes, I know it may not render, but for my use-case that is irrelevant)

Answer (score 2):

In addition of @Martin Honnen's answer pointing out that 153 is not the **UNICODE** point for the character ™, but 8482, and @Jim Garrison recomendation of `xsl:character-map` (if you can't correctly state the character set for your input source), here is the reazon for the error report from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#HTML_CHARDATA :

> Certain characters, specifically the
>   control characters #x7F-#x9F, are
>   legal in XML but not in HTML. It is a
>   serialization error [err:SERE0014] to
>   use the HTML output method when such
>   characters appear in the instance of
>   the data model. The serializer MUST
>   signal the error.